# Changing rqt_plot x-axis while it plays in real-time

Tags: rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm new and just going through the turtlesim tutorials. When I probe the variables with rqt_plot and watch them change over time, I would really like to expand the x-axis from a 5 second window to an *n*-second window, in order to see larger patterns, but I don't know how even after some googling. Thoughts? One can pause the graph and change x-min and x-max in the Figure options, but that only works when the graph is paused. The change vanishes once you turn auto-scrolling back on.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173417/changing-rqt_plot-x-axis-while-it-plays-in-real-time/) by [Eric Schneider](https://answers.ros.org/users/4619/eric-schneider/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2014-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yep. This is a bug in the matplotlib backend of the current released version of rqt_plot. If you have pyqtgraph or qwtplot installed, those backends tend to do a better job at this. (Click the little gear icon in the widget's title bar to switch backends)

The latest version from source no longer has this bug, as of yesterday. See https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/pull/239 and https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/issues/235

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on 2014-07-01**:
Is there a way to change the parameters in the X and Y axis, as well as their names, etc?
I want to plot, for example, my robot's velocity vs Current instead of velocity vs time.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-02**:
Sorry, no.